# RoR table join with "where" needed on both tables

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around joining tables. I have a one_to_many relationship between Locations and Listings. Locations have a longitude and latitude, as well as it's primary key: zipcode. Listings have a title and zipcode.

```
Listing.where("title LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search2]}%")
Location.where(:lat => @min_lat..@max_lat, :lon => @min_lon..@max_lon)
```

I'd basically Like to combine these two statements so that I can get all Listings within a given range of a zipcode, which is determnied by using a range of longitudes and latitudes. I can't figure out how to do this in Ruby on Rails in a fashion where I don't have to do separate SQL finds and loop through the data in my code to find the correct data.

Edit Updated code:

```
@results=Location.joins(:listings).where(:listings => ["title LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search2]}%"], :locations => {:zipcode => params[:searchZip]})
```

SQL output:`SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" INNER JOIN "listings" ON "listings"."location_id" = "locations"."zipcode" WHERE ("locations"."listings" IN ('title LIKE ?', '%fish%')) AND ("locations"."zipcode" = 44012)`

I don't know why it is doing "locations"."listings" (which gives an error), or where the IN is coming from.

Comment: Does location has the foreign key of listing?

Comment: Listing has the foreign key, location_id, to link listings to a location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly that `Location has_many :listings`, then this query will return all of the listings in the location range with matching titles:

```
Listing.joins(:location).where(
  'listings.title LIKE ? AND 
   locations.lat BETWEEN ? AND ? AND 
   locations.lon BETWEEN ? AND ?', 
"%#{params[:search2]}%", @min_lat, @max_lat, @min_lon, @max_lon)
```

Comment: This works as a temporary solution while I try to figure out a better RoR/ARel approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using ARel as opposed to writing your own SQL:

```
Listing.joins(:location).
  where(:listings => {:lat => @min_lat..@max_lat, :lon => @min_lon..@max_lon},
        :location => ["title LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search2]}%"])
```

Comment: I've tried that, I don't think it's as simple as adding a comma and inserting the second search term. I'm getting SQL output: ("locations"."locations" IN ('title LIKE %?%', '%%')) from the second part of the where clause.

Comment: Ah-ha, I've actually got a typo (notice the two sets of `%`).  I've edited my answer to be correct.

Comment: I updated code up top and my continued problem. I changed the lat/lon stuff to just the zipcode for simplicities sake for the moment.

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Comment: Also, please post the relevant relationships from your models (has_many, belongs_to, etc).

Comment: Listing belongs_to location and Location has_many listings. I'm using rails 3.0.

Comment: @BrettBender let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1418/discussion-between-kyle-patterson-and-brett-bender)

Answer (score 0):

```
   Location.joins(:listings).where(:listings => {:lat => @min_lat..@max_lat, :lon => @min_lon..@max_lon} )
```

Comment: but that doesn't incorporate the where for the listing title:
    "title LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search2]}%"

Comment: It's the same > you could put it like :

Comment: Location.joins(:listings).where(:listings => {:lat => @min_lat..@max_lat, :lon => @min_lon..@max_lon}, :locations => { CONDITION } )

Comment: something like Brett Bender copied it / sugested you